# Problems running poLCA.entropy

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I am trying to conduct an LCA analysis in R using the poLCA package. I am currently trying to get the entropy values for my data, but I keep getting the same message: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 4, 3

I have already tried deleting all the NAs from my database and created a new database without the missing cases. I am exporting my database from xlsl into R. I have also been trying to run the data with equations, but it doesn't work. I keep getting the same output.

```
#### Uploading database ####
LCA.women1=read.xlsx("LCA.women1.xlsx", sheet = 1)
str(LCA.women1)
LCA.women1=LCA.women1[,2:21]
### Running LCA ###
lcawomen1 <- poLCA(lcawperu, data=LCA.women1, maxiter=5000, tol=1e-10, na.rm=TRUE, probs.start=NULL, nclass=1, nrep=100, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)
lcawomen2 <- poLCA(lcawperu, data=LCA.women1, maxiter=5000, tol=1e-10, na.rm=TRUE, probs.start=NULL, nclass=2, nrep=100, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)
## Entropy measures ##
log(prod(sapply(lcawomen2$probs,ncol)))
p.hat <- lcawomen2$predcell$observed/lcawomen2$N
H.hat <- -sum(p.hat * log(p.hat))
H.hat
poLCA.entropy(lcawomen2)

### Entropy equations ###
entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
error_prior <- entropy(lcawomen2$P)
error_post <- mean(apply(lcawomen2$posterior, 1, entropy))
R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post / error_prior)

### another method ###
results$R2_entropy
results[1,8]<-c("-")
error_prior<-entropy(lcawomen2$P) # class proportions model 2
error_post<-mean(apply(lcawomen2$posterior,1, entropy),na.rm = TRUE)
results[2,8]<-round(((error_prior-error_post) / error_prior),3)
```

This is the structure of my data after running dput(head(LCAwomen2, 30)). All NAs have been changed into 3:
structure(list(w1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), w2 = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), w3 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    w4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), w5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), w6 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1), w7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), w8 = c(2, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), w9 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    1, 3), w10 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1), w11 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), w12 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 2), w13 = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), 
    w14 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), w15 = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), w16 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), w17 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), w18 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), w19 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), w20 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Which function is giving you that error? Also can you share your data so others can help? Just from a quick look it seems that you are logging something - if it has 0s it will return -Inf which might mess up your analysis.

Comment: also is all of that code needed or can you simplify it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I run the poLCA.entropy I get that error. The data runs perfectly with poLCA, but when I try to get the entropy values, it doesn't work. I am mainly trying to run it using poLCA.entropy, but if I run it using function and error_post or prior doesn't work either.

Comment: I am not sure how to upload my data. I am new to stack overflow!

Comment: There is a command called `dput` that will help, after you load your data do this `dput(LCA.women1)` , if your dataset is very large do `dput(head(LCA.women1, 50))` to just give a subset of your data. you can copy and paste the output of the `dput` function to your question